# How to change the XML to Configuration Classes?

Tags: spring, configuration, annotations, spring-batch, cglib

I'm sorry, I little hate English.

please help me. I having an Issue.
It's I want to change XML to Java Class  for @Configuration and @Bean use it.
How do I do ??

The following is that I'd like to change.
I don't know 'module-context.xml' especially...
just I want know that.

**launch-context.xml**

```
<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml" />

<bean id="jobOperator"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator"
    p:jobLauncher-ref="jobLauncher" p:jobExplorer-ref="jobExplorer"
    p:jobRepository-ref="jobRepository" p:jobRegistry-ref="jobRegistry" />
<bean id="jobExplorer"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="SpringDataSource" />
<bean id="jobRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
</bean>
<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="SpringDataSource" p:transactionManager-ref="springTransactionManager" />

<bean id="placeholderProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:batch.properties" />
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="SpringDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${batch.jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${batch.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${spring.batch.jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${spring.batch.jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
<bean id="springTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="SpringDataSource" />
</bean>
```

**module-context.xml**

```
<job id="job1" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    incrementer="jobParametersIncrementer">
    <step id="simple-step" parent="simpleStep">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="exampleReader" writer="exampleWriter" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
<bean id="exampleReader"
    class="jp.co.app.cm.nochunk.ExampleItemReader" />
<bean id="exampleWriter"
    class="jp.co.app.cm.nochunk.ExampleItemWriter" />
<bean id="simpleStep"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleStepFactoryBean"
    abstract="true">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="springTransactionManager" />
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="startLimit" value="100" />
</bean>
```

plase tell me someone?

Answer (score 3):

First four beans translated, this should be enough for you to start and grasp the idea:

```
@Configuration
public class Spring {

    @Bean
    public MapJobRegistry mapJobRegistry() {
        return new MapJobRegistry();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor() {
        JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor pp = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
        pp.setJobRegistry(mapJobRegistry());
        return pp;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher() {
        SimpleJobLauncher jl = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jl.setJobRepository(jobRepository().getObject());
        return jl;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean() {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean fb = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        fb.setDataSource(springDataSource());
        fb.setTransactionManager(springTransactionManager());
        return fb;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Tomasz. I was try it. but I can't still resolve that. How do I implements <job>tag ? if you can tell me, please show me that part of sample code.

Comment: @user1702995: good question! I don't know Spring Batch and whether it supports Java configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but just in case someone will hit this post via Google.
Java configuration was added to spring batch starting version 2.2.

> Until 2.2.0 the only option for configuring a job was via XML (either
>   through the batch DSL or by hand). However, in 2.2.0, Java based
>   configuration has been added as a way to define Spring Batch Jobs. To
>   support this new configuration option, an annotation and builder
>   classes have been added.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/reference/html/whatsNew.html#whatsNewJavaConfiguration
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/reference/html/configureJob.html#javaConfig

You can find an example here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/2.2.x/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/config